# How to use two <form-login/> in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a project in which I need two different login form e.g: **user** and for **admin** login. User login form is working fine for me. This is what I have in my security.xml file

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <!-- <csrf /> -->
    <headers>
        <cache-control />
        <content-type-options />
        <hsts />
        <frame-options />
        <xss-protection />
    </headers>
    <!-- requires-channel="https" -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/dashboard*"
        access="hasAnyRole('${role.master}')" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/logged" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE" />
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" />
    </session-management>
    <remember-me token-validity-seconds="86400" />
</http>
```

In the above code it's working fine for **/login** page but I want to add another form for **/administrator** but when I tried to add another form tag in same  It's not working.

I searched about this on google but none of them help me to solve my issue. I also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756773/multiple-login-form-in-spring-security) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209962/spring-security-with-multiple-login-pages) issue.

Can anyone help me what I'm doing wrong here.

**This code is working fine but only for single login page.**

Comment: Seperate `http` config blocks.

Comment: You cannot just add a separate `http` block you need to differentiate with a `pattern` else it won't work. You need to have separate `http` blocks for your normal users section and admin section.

Comment: As I stated... The `http` element has a `pattern` property, when having multiple `http` elements you need to specify a `pattern` for which this block is relevant. If you omit that it will match all requests, which is generally not what you want when having multiple `http` elements.

Comment: The Spring Security reference guide and there are answered questions here on stack overflow.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for reference I understand what I was doing wrong some spring documentation and your link helped me a lot to solve my issue.